# Salesforce1 Mobile Push Notifications, for chatter group posts

Tags: salesforce1-platform

I am trying to develop a feature, which is based on push notification support on S1 mobile, i.e. "**Someone posts to a group you belong to**". This group notification is not coming as Mobile push notification for me, I tried all of the following settings.

Please Note: *Normal @mention push notifications are coming on time and correctly always*.

Any suggestions would be helpful regarding the same.

Following are the settings, I tried in mobile and desktop.

This group push notification could be enabled by opening S1 mobile's left menu > settings > push notifications

[image]

Additionally per following suggestion in this [Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000194290&language=en_US), I've changed group settings for emailing on every post.
[image]

Following are the group settings for sending email notifications for each post:
[image]

Apart from that Salesforce > Setup > Notifications > Salesforce1 Notifications is turned on for all possible actions (pic below)

[image]

Here are Android and App versions for reference

[image: Salesforce App Version]

[image: Android Version]

Comment: Do other S1 notifications work fine?

Comment: Yes remaining all normal @mention push notifications are coming pretty well.

Comment: I presume (from the screenshot) this is Android. Can you confirm the SF1 app version as well as your Android version? There was an update made on Play Store yesterday - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter&hl=en

Comment: Thanks ! Added the pics of same @GauravKheterpal to the post. I am on latest version of the S1 App, and Android is little behind 5.x

Comment: By the way same is happening in iPad as well during our tests. Normal @mention push notifications come really well, but group ones are not working at all.

Comment: Just wondering I have more options in my Salesforce1 setting then yours and don't have this 'Someone posts to a group you belong to". Version is same.

Comment: And I just tried it i am getting both email and push notifications whenever someone post to group (without any mention).

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani, can you please share your app version, mobile os, and Org edition ?

Comment: App version is same as yours, os is android 5.0.1, org is winter 16 developer edition.

Comment: Gaurav and Ashwani -  we were able to nail down this issue a bit. Surprisingly this error is only coming in PDE (Partner Dev Org), we signed up normal dev org, and group push notifications are working. PDE's are meant to be more powerful then normal DE's not sure about the problem. Support case is raised via Partner Community now, will keep everyone posted about the findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got following response from Salesforce support, its a bug in some Salesforce environments. Please check response from support team below for more details:

> I checked and we have a bug on this Push notifications on SF1. As this
>   Bug is related that on few environments it is working and on few it is
>   not. As this is a new feature which is added in SF1 and we are seeing
>   many user cases on the similar types. We have Bug W-2890608 which was
>   raised and investigation is going on. We do not have ETA on this. But
>   still I am checking on this and would also update information very
>   soon.

Answer (score 3):

The status for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBasAAE) is 'PARTIAL DELIVERY' and I see the same issue reported on this in the comments so IMO, this may be broken.

[image]

However, the comments from Salesforce product management does state it is available.

FWIW, I just did a quick test on my Nexus and it did not pop a notification when someone else posted on the same Chatter group. I would recommend raising a support case to find out the status of what's going on here.

[image]